# How to simulate the style of date picker in iPad mini2's Calendar in iOS by HTML

Tags: html, ios, datepicker

I know the `<select>` tag can show me the style, but it shows only one colum of option.

`<input type="date">` is almost what I want, but I need to custom the options.

How can it show multiple colums of option by HTML in iOS?

[image: date picker in iPad mini2's Calendar App]